# sort array list from second item android

Tags: android

i have a array list for using it in spinner ,i have first value i spinner as title and i want to sort array list from second item in the spinner but i dont know how to do this i am using below trick but it sort whole array list including first item which is title so how to statr sorting from second item...
my code is below...

```
 // this is my title ie. "provincia"
    String select2= "Provincia";
       if(!estado1.contains(select2)){
          estado1.add(select2);
          }

     for (int i = 0; i < sitesList1.getEstado().size(); i++)
     {
         if(!estado1.contains(sitesList1.getEstado().get(i))) 
            {

             estado1.add(sitesList1.getEstado().get(i));
                  Collections.sort(estado1);

            }
```

use below code for show it in spinner...

```
 final ArrayList<String> estado1 = MainMenu.barrio1;
     final Spinner estado11 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Spinner04);
     ArrayAdapter<String> adapterbarrio = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
           android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, estado1)

           estado11.setAdapter(adapterbarrio);
```

Comment: 1. **you calling sort in every iteration??!!!??** 2. (answer) simply you can't( sorting from second item) ... but if first item will starts with withspace(fx. " ") or "-" it will always be first ... or ... remove first item, store it in temp, sort rest, and insert temp item at first position with add(0, temp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to split the arraylist like

```
estado1.subList(1,estado1.size()-1);
```

This would return a sublist excluding your title.

Answer (score 2):

Why not remove the title / only add the title after the list has been sorted?

Answer (score 2):

How about this

```
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    // Fill list
    String title = list.get(0);
    list.remove(0);
    Collections.sort(list);
    list.add(0, title);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use bubble sort! and start at index = 1!

```
final ArrayList<String> estado1;
for(int i=1; i<estado1.size() ; i++) {
     for(int c=i; c<estado.size() ; c++) {
          if(estado1.get(i).compareTo(estado1.get(c)))
          {
               String temp = estado1.get(i);
               estado1.remove(i);
               estado1.add(i, estado1.get(c));
               estado1.remove(c);
               estado1.add(c, temp);
          }
     }
}
```

**PS: very bad performance**

Comment: You could use `set`. That would avoid internal array shifting and would perform way better. For bigger lists I would recommend merge sort anyway.

Comment: @Knickedi did you -1? I have intentionally added `PS: very bad performance` so I guess one can learn that this is bad programming?

Comment: No, wasn't me. I would've mentioned that. I usually never down vote without leaving a good reason. You added a note so your answer was and is perfectly fine ;-)